# Entity Framework migration does not generate the identity column

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have a model with an integer property called Id, which when I do the migration does not generate the Id property as Identity.

This is the Fluent API (One-to-zero/one relationship) configuration.

```
Property(fv => fv.Id) //I just put this property to summarize
  .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
  .HasColumnName("Codigo");

HasOptional(fv => fv.Presupuesto)
  .WithOptionalDependent(p => p.FacturaVenta)
  .Map(m => m.MapKey("PresupuestoCodigo"));
```

And when making the migration, the migration appears in this way:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
       "dbo.FacturaVentas",
       c => new
       {
           Codigo = c.Int(nullable: false), //Why is not Identity?
           PresupuestoCodigo = c.Int(),
       })
       .PrimaryKey(t => t.Codigo)
       .ForeignKey(t => t.PresupuestoCodigo)
       .Index(t => t.Codigo)
}
```

these are my models:

```
public class FacturaVenta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Presupuesto Presupuesto { get; set; }
}

public class Presupuesto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public FacturaVenta FacturaVenta { get; set; }
}
```

How can i resolve that?

Comment: It should create identity column even w/o `.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`. There must be something not shown in your example. For instance, one-to-one relationship?

Comment: I edited my question, here I am using the One-to-zero/one relationship.

Comment: Even with the updated example, I can't reproduce (I'm getting `Codigo = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),`). There must be something else. I would suggest you trying to reproduce with new clean project and only the code from the question. Then you'll probably find what's different in your real code.

Answer (score 3):

Just came around this myself today, and it seems that sometimes Entity Framework doesn't figure out that a column is auto generated. You can use the attribute [`DatabaseGenerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8) with a value of [`DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption?view=netframework-4.8) to force Entity Framework to add the `identity: true` value in your migration.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace MyApp {
  public class MyEntity {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }
}
```

If the entities are related as zero/one to one you can also set the id of the related entity as the Key property

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MyApp {
  public class MyForeignEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }

  public class MyEntity {
    [Key]
    public int ForeignId { get; set; }
    public virtual MyForeignEntity Foreign { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In which case the id is already set up to work.